# Best practice for the directory/location of your interfaces (as in implements)

Tags: actionscript-3, design-patterns, interface

**What is best practice for the directory/location of your interfaces? (as in implements)** 
in the folder with the class you are interfacing? an interface folder in the source root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't differentiate between an interface and a class when choosing package structure.

Since you're almost certainly using interfaces to make your API cleaner, you should imagine that you are giving your code to another experienced AS3 coder; where would they expect to find the class/interface within a SWC? There's no reason that they should differentiate between an interface and a class, given that they can't see the code anyway.

Comment: OK I think I understand, so your saying that if I have say multiple views, in various sub directory of views etc I would probably just put ISort in the root view folder?

Comment: I think it's reasonable that you'd put it in the relevant common package, so if you had src/app/view/suba/SubViewA.as and src/app/view/subb/SubViewB.as then I guess your interface would be src/app/view/IView.as.

There's also no reason why they should be sub-classed themselves, they could all inhabit src/app/view/ as well. As I say, there are no rules for this sort of thing, except for the principle that you shouldn't differentiate between a class and an interface for the sake of packaging.

Comment: By the way, there is also no real reason why an Interface should have an I prepending it, though many people do, including Adobe! I have tended to omit the I in my more recent libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a question with a back-and-white answer.  That said, it is my personal opinion that it makes most sense for an interface to live in the same package as the classes which implement it (or as close as possible).  That way others who use your code can infer some thing about the interface and its intended use from the package structure.
When all the interfaces are in an "interface" folder on the root 1 - that folder can get really big & ugly, 2 - the interfaces are totally disconnected from all the related files, so it's more difficult to move them around as a group,  3 - your only clue about what the interface does (without actually opening it or importing it and examining its docs and members) is the file name.

Comment: just a note on language here, *infer* is to derive by reasoning from premises, nuance or evidence. When you intend to convey meaning, you imply, connote, suggest etc.

Comment: @Slomojo lol, grammar overflow?
You are correct that when you're the one creating the package structure you are (or ought to be) using it to *imply* something about the files within, but my usage is still correct. Those implications, connotations, suggestions are meant to be derived, deduced, *inferred*, etc. by someone viewing the files.  Perhaps my use of the word "you" threw you off.

Comment: fair, but in the previous wording the context of "you" was ambiguous. Since you were explaining how someone would place their interfaces within the package structure, 'you' appeared to be aimed at the person constructing organisation of Interfaces. The rewording certainly clears it up. ;)